# How to align text both left and right side equally

Tags: css

How to align text both left and right side equally?Can anyone help me?

example:
[image]

my code:

```css
p {
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consecteture adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volupat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendr</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
p {
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consecteture adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volupat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendr</p>
</div>
```